# Creation of new field that will point the next empty position of an array

Tags: c#

A little bit background - 
my assignment is to create new classes and to use them in each other.
there are 3 classes - `Manager`,`Employee` and `Store`.
How do I create a new field (in class `Store`) that will point the next null position on the array of type `Employee`? I don't even know how to create this field.

```
class Store
{
    //Fields
    string name;
    Manager manager;
    Employee[] employees = new Employee[5]  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a List instead of an Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refer to the contents of the array by index. Since you need to keep track of the number of items in the array anyway, the current number of elements will always point to the next item of the array:

```
class Store
{
    //Fields
    string name;
    Manager manager;
    Employee[] employees = new Employee[5];
    int employeeCount = 0;
}
```

You should not forget to maintain your item count when you add and remove items to your array. You should also be aware that you need to move the following items up when you remove items for the middle of the array.

When you use a `List`, it will do all of this for you, but I guess this is not the point of your assignment.